# How to block images and their ALT tags on Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, images, browser-addons

I use this addon to block images in Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/ . And this one to block in Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj . The Firefox one blocks the images and displays alt text in place of images but the chrome one does not . Is there any way to not display alt text when images are blocked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/umatrix/) instead. Whitelist the other types of resources for every site (such as cookies and scripts), and then control images as you want:

> **[uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/umatrix/)**
>
> Point & click to forbid/allow any class of requests made by your
>   browser. Use it to block scripts, iframes, ads, facebook, etc.